# Calabi-Yau manifold with fiber structure

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the paper 'A bound on the Euler number for certain Calabi-Yau 3-folds' where the author made the following statement about fiberd Calabi-Yau manifold without proof.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective threefold with trivial canonical bundle, $\pi:X\to Y$ be a surjective holomorphic map from $X$ to a lower dimensional manifold $Y$, if $F$ is the general fiber of $\pi$, then there are 3 possible types:

- a. $Y$= surface with kodaira dimension $-\infty$, $F$=elliptic curves;
- b. $Y= \mathbb{C}P^1$, $F$= abelian surface;
- c. $Y= \mathbb{C}P^1$, $F$= k3-surface.

The author mentioned that $F$ should have trivial canonical bundle by ajunction formula, as far as I know, the ajunction formula says that
$$K_F=(K_X\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(F))\mid_F,$$
then $K_F=\mathcal{O}_X(F)\mid_F,$ so the problem is why $\mathcal{O}_X(F)\mid_F=\mathcal{O}_F$?

And I can't see why the base manifold $Y$ should be either a surface with kodaira dimension $-\infty$ or $\mathbb{C}P^1$?

The author also mentioned implicitly that if $\pi$ have no singular fibers, then $X$ is essentially a product. This is amazing since this is the main result of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3773) paper in 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a smooth fiber of a proper map $f: X \to Y$ then the normal bundle $N_{F/X}$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle $T_{y}Y \otimes O_F$, where $y = f(F) \in Y$. Therefore
$$
\omega_F \cong \omega_X\vert_F \otimes \det N_{F/X}
$$
(this is the adjunction formula, your version is only for divisors), hence $K_F = 0$.

Comment: thank you! Can you say something about the base manifold Y?

Answer (score 0):

By Viehweg's resolution of the Iitaka $C_{3,1}$ conjecture,  if $p : X \to S$ is a fiber space with general fiber $F$,  then $\kappa(X) \geq \kappa(F) + \kappa(S)$.  In our case,  $\kappa(X) = \kappa(F) =0$,  and so $\kappa(S) \leq 0$, i.e., $\kappa(S) =0$ or $\kappa(S) = -\infty$.  Since $X$ is simply connected and $h^{2,0}(X) =0$,  one can show that the same is true for $S$.  By the Enriques--Kodaira classification,  there is no simply connected complex surface with $h^{2,0}=0$ and $\kappa(S)=0$; therefore, $\kappa(S) = - \infty$.  The same argument shows that if the fibers are surfaces,  the base is a curve of negative Kodaira dimension, i.e., $\mathbf{P}^1$.